# Access appsettings.json custom section inside my asp.net core console application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have the following `appsettings.json` inside my Asp.NET core console application:-

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=ServiceDesk;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "SP": {
    "SiteURL": "https://***.sharepoint.com/"
  }
}
```

now i want to access the `SiteURL`, i tired the following but it did not work:-

```
var section = config.GetSection("SP");
var ClientConfig = section.GetChildren();
string siteUrl = ClientConfig.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model that matches the settings to store the data

```
public class SharePointOptions {
    public string SiteURL { get; set; }
}
```

Then bind to the section from configuration

```
SharePointOptions options = config.GetSection("SP").Get<SharePointOptions>();
string siteUrl = options.SiteURL;
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern)

> `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` binds and returns the specified type. `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` may be more convenient than using `ConfigurationBinder.Bind`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get value from configuration by key like this.

appsettings.json

```
{
    "key": "value"
}
```

- 

```
var v = config["key"];
```

for nested values use `Parent:Key` notation